# Class defined in Objective-C and Swift, which one gets executed?

Tags: objective-c, swift

I have a project with mixed Objective-C and Swift source files.

Foo.h

```
@interface Foo : NSObject
-(void) sayHello;    
@end
```

Foo.m

```
@implementation Foo
-(void) sayHello {
    NSLog(@"Hello world, from Objective-C with love.");
}
@end
```

Foo.swift

```
class Foo {
    func sayHello() {
        print("Hello world, from Swift with love.")
    }
}
```

Is it even possible to include both Foo classes in the same `Xcode` project? If so, which `sayHello` method one will be executed?

Answer (score 1):

Don't worry, Xcode will ask you to bridge it or not.

It is documented here https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/MixandMatch.html

Comment: So if you don't bridge it, the Objective-C version will get executed. And if you do, the Swift version gets executed?

Answer (score 1):

It depends. If your project is in Swift and you are importing Objective-C files, the `Foo` class in the Swift file will be executed.

If you are working on a Objective-C project importing a Swift file, on one hand, you know that you'll have access to the `Foo` Objective-C class if you import it via: `#import "Foo.h"`. On the other hand, you'll be calling the class in Swift by using `#import "ModuleName-Swift.h"`. (You need to replace ModuleName with your project's module name). However, you cannot have `#import "Foo.h"` and `#import "ModuleName-Swift.h"` at the same time; You'll get a duplicate class error (of that sort). Also, if you want to use the class in the Swift file, `Foo` must be a subclass of `NSObject`:

```
class Foo: NSObject { ... }
```